# Moleculer metrics port not exposed in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, moleculer

I'm using molecule for microservices.
Actually I don't know how to expose the metrics port (3030) in the docker container  to be able to read metrics from http://host:3030/metrics

when the app is executed ion my localhost it is working just fine but when deploying with docker-compose --build -up it don't work.

### my docker compose traefik section

```
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true" # Don't do that in production!
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
    ports:
      - 3000:80
      - 3001:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - internal
      - default
```

Thank you for your help

The all docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
    image: moleculer-akwa
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    environment:
      SERVICES: api
      PORT: 3000
    depends_on:
      - nats
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api-gw.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.api-gw.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
    networks:
      - internal
        
  firebase:
    build:
      context: .
    image: moleculer-akwa
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    environment:
      SERVICES: firebase
    depends_on:
      - nats
    networks:
      - internal
        
  kafka:
    build:
      context: .
    image: moleculer-akwa
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    environment:
      SERVICES: kafka
    depends_on:
      - nats
    networks:
      - internal

  mailer:
    build:
      context: .
    image: moleculer-akwa
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    environment:
      SERVICES: mailer
    depends_on:
      - nats
    networks:
      - internal

  sms:
    build:
      context: .
    image: moleculer-akwa
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    environment:
      SERVICES: sms
    depends_on:
      - nats
    networks:
      - internal
        
  
  io:
    build:
      context: .
    image: moleculer-akwa
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    environment:
      SERVICES: io
      PORT: 5000
    depends_on:
      - nats
    networks:
      - internal

  nats:
    image: nats:2
    networks:
      - internal

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true" # Don't do that in production!
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
    ports:
      - 3000:80
      - 3001:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - internal
      - default

networks:
  internal:

volumes:
  data:
```

Update:
When running `npm run dev` on my local machine I can access metrics url at http://localhost:3030/metrics to get metrics for all running microservices.
But when I deploy the code to the container (docker-compose.yml above) the application run perfectly on http://host:3000 but http://localhost:3030/ is not accessible.
I disabled the firewall but no luck
I added port mapping 3030:3030 on traefik section on the docker-compose.yml file but nothing

```
ports:
          - 3000:80
          - 3001:8080
          - 3030:3030
```

Thank you for your help and your patience

Comment: Why not just add one more port mapping `- 3030:3030` ?

Comment: Try 80 or 8080 it may work for you.

Comment: I already added the mapping 3030:3030 but it don't work

Comment: You need to add details about what is going wrong. Try adding logs, or being specific about what doesn't work. Further, your docker compose file does not contain the mapping referenced above, and it's not clear which container you're trying to get metrics from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it
In docker-compose.yml on the api service declaration just added ports: 3030:3030

```
api:
build:
  context: .
environment:
  SERVICES: api
  PORT: 3000
depends_on:
  - nats
ports:
  - 3030:3030
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.api-gw.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)"
  - "traefik.http.services.api-gw.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
networks:
  - internal
```

Thank you

Comment: It will only expose the metrics from the "api" node and not from others. Every Moleculer nodes collects the metrics locally, so you should add all nodes to Prometheus to collect metrics from all nodes. So @André's answer the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Prometheus as exporter? If that's the case then please check https://github.com/AndreMaz/moleculer-prometheus-demo

Comment: Yes i'm using Prometheuse as exporter but I already have prometheuse server installed on another platforms I just need the metrics to be available at http://host:3030/metrics